# Are enums initialized correctly when they are read from a data source?

Tags: typescript, loopback4

In Loopback 4, you can create models which are then connected to a data source to write them out and read them back in.

So let's say I have this enum:

```
enum Priority {
  LOW = "LOW",
  MEDIUM = "MEDIUM",
  HIGH = "HIGH"
};
```

Using the [Typescript playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play) this compiles to:

```
var Priority;
(function (Priority) {
    Priority["LOW"] = "LOW";
    Priority["MEDIUM"] = "MEDIUM";
    Priority["HIGH"] = "HIGH";
})(Priority || (Priority = {}));
```

So the values are strings, therefore a database (e.g. MySQL) would be able to store this value without problem.

But let's say this is being read from a database. What is going to be the resulting type? Will I get a runtime error?

Answer (score 2):

Typescript types are erased at runtime - values of your enum type will simply be strings at runtime. Extracting a string with one of the expected values for your enum from the database, and then treat it as a value of type `Priority` will behave as you want.

You only need to ensure that no other code accessing the database sets the priority to value different from the three given ones.

Answer (score 1):

No, you will not get a runtime error because [types are erased](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/FAQ#what-is-type-erasure) at runtime.

When reading your *priority* field from the database you will likely get it as `string` because it is stored as such.
To maintain type safety you can use what's known as a [type assertion](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#type-assertions). That way you explicitly tell the compiler the string from the database is of type `Priority`.

For example:

```
enum Priority {
  LOW = "LOW",
  MEDIUM = "MEDIUM",
  HIGH = "HIGH"
};

function readPriority(): string {
  return "LOW";
}

const priority = readPriority() as Priority;
```

[TypeScript Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/KYOwrgtgBACgTgSwPaIC4E8oG8BQUoAyA8gOpQC8UARMSVQDR5QCyAogCICSAqsxdWy68GTABKcA4qP5VxUqjgC+Abhw4AZmBABjVMhBQ4wAIYATeMjToAFAEoAXFADOqRCADm2JkdRg4BmlIqVUU1bSQQFygAB0QUBAx+IzMLeIw7KGMnWDirZSA)